# How to maintiain AngularJS functions after asp UpdatePanel partial postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my Web Forms project, I've got a an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and within the panel's `<ContentTemplate>` I'm using a couple of radio button groups derived from the [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) example.
When the page performs a partial post-back in the UpdatePanel, I lose the Angular functionality and my Angular directives no longer control the radio button groups and their current selected buttons.

Granted, I've seen examples of how to call Javascript functions after a partial postbacks such as `endRequestHandler` and `pageLoad` but I'm not particularly sure how to craft this in such a way to work with Angular. The angular module is declared at the top of the page like

`<html lang="en" ng-app="NewHireFormsManagement">`

**Here is a short and sweet version of the code I have now...**

**ASP.NET**

```
<!-- Pull hidden data to set current radio button positions -->
<asp:Label ID="FormStatusCurrentStatusLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<script type="text/javascript">

        // Bind client-side events before/after async page-load
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        // Set and Update Form Status
        var ITUpdateStatusRadios = function ($scope) {
            $scope.radioModel = '<%= this.FormStatusCurrentStatusLabel.Text %>';
        };
    }

</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ITadminStatusUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div ng-controller="ITUpdateStatusRadios">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Attention_Needed'">
                    <i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>&nbsp;Attention Needed
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Pending'">
                    <i class='fa fa-paper-plane-o'></i>&nbsp;Pending
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Complete'">
                    <i class='fa fa-check'></i>&nbsp;Complete
                </label>
            </div>
            <!-- Pull Results from this label on form submit -->
            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="FormStatusNewStatusInput" value="{{radioModel || 'null'}}">
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="ITStatusUpdateSubmitButton" runat="server" OnClick="AdminStatusUpdateSubmitButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Update" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C# Code-Behind**

```
    // Page Load
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...SQL stored procedure query 

        this.FormStatusCurrentStatusLabel.Text = sqlITFormStatusDataReader["CompletionStatus"].ToString(); // Current Form Completion status
    }

    // Update Button
    protected void AdminStatusUpdateSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            .. prepair sql connection
            updateformsqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udAdminCompletionStatus", FormStatusNewStatusInput.Value);
            .. call stored procedure and update value
        }
        catch()
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Basically, the initial radio position is set dynamically based on data read from a database on on `Page_Load`. When 'Update' button is pressed, another event is called to update the same database table and then the current radio position would ideally be re-set in real time, again on `Page_Load`. It's just that the JS function is being lost for Angular.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. UpdatePanel replaces your existing html. Angular isn't bound to your new innerHtml. Honestly I advise against using ASP webforms with any js libraries unless you are a js/web guru. At which point web forms makes no sense either....If you do want to continue down this road you need to get ASP to run some JavaScript to handle the rebind of the html update. NB asp webforms is one of the most painful technologies i have ever worked with.

Comment: @Aron maybe I could use StringBuilder in C# and just call run the function on Page_Load? Otherwise I could skip the UpdatePanel all together and redirect back to the page to reflect the changes. It's to late in the game for me to divert from webforms but maybe next time I should try the MVC approach.

Comment: It is clear you don't clearly understand each scope and lifecycle. The problem is that webforms is incompatible with ng. Webforms is moving the cheese from under ng. So you need to tell webforms to tell ng where the new cheese is. In javascript, CLIENT SIDE. There is a property in UpdatePanel to set a client side callback after update. Use that. Or alternatively and more correctly get rid of all the update panels and use ng to fetch the days and bind it. Or thirdly get rid of ng. But to get the two techs to work together you need to have a deep understanding of both.

Comment: @Aron I knew the html is being replaced somewhere but I just wasn't sure where to connect the dots. I'll take a look at that UpdatePanel property and see if I can get that to work for me. I appreciate the input.

Comment: You're going to be pulling every strand of hair out of your head by the end of your project if you're trying to combine webforms with a front-end library like Angular.

Comment: @Alex Ford Probably so. It's been going fair so far with the exception of async functions. I suppose the best solution for this project would be to try and avoid using Angular within UpdatePanel. Angular has grown on me but I'm also more familiar with WebForms than dev patterns like MVC. I need to learn though.